# Update Hosts file with .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to update my hosts file at our sites with 2 rules.

1. Ip address should be change from the current ip we have saved in hosts file:
   111.111.111.111 -> 111.111.111.222
2. If there is no IP address that matches the 111.111.111.222 add it at the end of the line;

1st part works fine, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the 2nd rule...

currently what I have
.

```
@echo off

set newip=111.111.111.222

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%A in (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) do (

set line0=%%A

set line1=!line0:111.111.111.111=%newip%!

echo=!line1!>>C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts

)

endlocal


move /y C:\Windows\System32\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

pause
```

How should I approach it?

Comment: If anyone will be interested I found the answer.

You need to add these lines after endlocal 

FINDSTR /I "111.111.111.222" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts

If "%errorlevel%" == "0" goto :sub_command  


echo 111.111.111.222 >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts

:sub_command

move /y C:\Windows\System32\drivers\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "oldip=111.111.111.111"
set "newip=111.111.111.222"

pushd "%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc" || (
    >&2 echo Failed to change directory.
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist "hosts" (
    >&2 echo Failed to find file named hosts.
    exit /b 1
)

(
    set "updated_entry="

    for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (hosts) do @(
        if "%%~A" == "%oldip%" (
            echo %newip% %%B
            set "updated_entry=defined"
        ) else (
            if "%%~A" == "%newip%" set "updated_entry=defined"
            echo %%A %%B
        )
    )

    if not defined updated_entry echo %newip% ?domain?
) > "hosts.tmp"

move /y "hosts.tmp" "hosts"
if exist "hosts.tmp" del "hosts.tmp"
```

Change to `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc` directory so the directory
with the `hosts` file is the current directory. Check if the hosts file
does exist to continue.

The `for` options of `tokens=1*` will store the ip address in `%%A` and
the remainder of the current line in `%%B`. Comparing the new ip address
with the ip address read is done with `"%%~A" == "%oldip%"`.

If the update of the ip address is not done, as the variable named
`updated_entry` is defined if it has, then it will write it at the
end of the file. Not sure what domain to insert so using just `?domain?`.

The new file with changes is `hosts.tmp` which is renamed to `hosts`.
`hosts.tmp` will be deleted if something fails, just to cleanup.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it looks much more effective. I'll give it a try with our next deployment.

Comment: Updated to comply with rule 2 of adding ip address to end of file if ip address is not replaced. Sorry, I initially missed that condition.